# parent and child database schema

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have one table named as `user`

USER(Table)

```
user_id      name     status_privilege(0=child,1=parent)    added_user_id
   2          abc                    1
   13       child_1                  0                          2
   14       child_2                  0                          2
```

I want display `user_id = 2`(parent's) data in all `user_id = 14,15` (all child's login). And also I want to display `user_id = 14 , 15`'s data in `user_id = 2`'s data. (Viceversa)

So for that what to do ?

I tried this query.

```
SELECT *,child.user_id as child_user_id,parent.user_id as parent_user_id
FROM user as parent
INNER JOIN user as child ON parent.user_id = child.user_added_id
WHERE child.user_id = '14'
```

so I got **child_user_id = 14 & parent_user_id = 2**

But I want that when I put below query it give me blank result.  (changed `child.user_id = '2'`)

```
SELECT *,child.user_id as child_user_id,parent.user_id as parent_user_id
FROM user as parent
INNER JOIN user as child ON parent.user_id = child.user_added_id
WHERE child.user_id = '2'
```

So I want is that when I fire query **single query** then if user is parent than also I want it's child's all data in `user_id ='2'` means data of 14 & 15 user's. And 2nd user_id's data in all childs.

Note : All the data in other tables are from `user_id` so is it possible ?
It's a requirement of existing project so I can not change database structure otherwise I can follow MySQL hierarchical of parent child structure.

Comment: What you need exactly please clerify?

Comment: i want to show all data of parent in all his childs and all childs data in parent.

Comment: Have you tried left join..?

Comment: So, to clarify: you want a single query that has one argument (user_id). You want output similar to that of your first query: If the user is a parent, you want one row per child of this user. If the user is a child, you want one row? I think this is your solution:
    `SELECT *,child.user_id as child_user_id,parent.user_id as parent_user_id FROM user as parent INNER JOIN user as child ON parent.user_id = child.added_user_id where child.user_id = '2' or parent.user_id='2';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is based on what i understand from the question is:
you want the full array of child user ids if parent user logged in and only one parent id if child user logged in.

so in php you can derived that via

```
<?php
    $user=array(); // this array will contains the user info
    $res=$db->query("select * from user where user_id='$id'"); //$id the user id with which you want to check whether it is parent or child.
    if($res->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row=$res->fetch_assoc();
        if($row['status_privilege']==0)
        {
            $res_main=$db->query("SELECT *,child.user_id as child_user_id,parent.user_id as parent_user_id FROM user as parent INNER JOIN user as child ON parent.user_id = child.user_added_id WHERE child.user_id = '".$row['user_id']."'");
            $user=$res_main->fetch_assoc();
        }
        else
        {
             $res_main=$db->query("SELECT * from user where added_user_id='".$row['user_id']."'");
             $user=$row;
             $user["child_array"]=array();
             while($row_child=$res_main->fetch_assoc())
             {
                  array_push($user['child_array'],$row_child['user_id']);
             }
        }
    }
    //you can further check that if user is parent or child by using this condition.
   if($user['status_privilege']==1)
   {
       //parent login it also contain the all child user ids
   }
   else
   {
       //child login it also contain the parent id as you have done it before.
   }
?>
```

Comment: ohk thank you so..much brother that's the solution what i needed :)